# How to add a background to UICollectionView like iBooks?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, ibooks, uicollectionviewlayout

iBooks app on ios,the bookshelf background will follow the books when scrolling.
Where can I add the background like iBooks?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are searching for

[How to Add a Decoration View to a UICollectionView](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/)